# Regex/KQL - Parse/Extract from Distinguished Name

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In Az Log Analytics, I am wanting to extract information from A DN

`cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=local,DC=com`

The goal is to extend to new columns: User = User One, Domain = internal.local.com

Haven't been able to find a good example to recreate this from in Kusto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator):

```
print input = 'cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=local,DC=com'
| parse input with "cn=" User "," * "DC=" d1 ",DC=" d2 ",DC=" d3
| project input, User, Domain = strcat_delim(".", d1, d2, d3)
```

| input | User | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=local,DC=com | User One | internal.local.com |

Or, if there is a variable number of occurrences of `DC=`:

```
datatable(input:string) [
    'cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=local,DC=com',
    'cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=com',
]
| parse input with "cn=" User "," * ",DC=" Domain
| extend Domain = replace_string(Domain, ",DC=", ".")
```

| input | User | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=local,DC=com | User One | internal.local.com |
| cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=com | User One | internal.com |

Comment: Yoni, if the input only had D1 & D2, how could the parse be amended to handle that. It appears if the input is

```'cn=User One,OU=Accounts,OU=Administrative,DC=internal,DC=com'```


That the resulting project string for Domain is = ..

Comment: if all inputs have that format, you can simply remove `d3` (and its leading comma) from the solution in the answer. otherwise, please clarify (perhaps, in a new post?) the assumptions that can or can't be made on the input

Comment: At most, we would have two different results from the query. DC=internal,DC=local,DC=com and/or DC=internal,DC=com. It seems that when presented with the latter, the Domain result is ..

Just wondering if there is a way to handle that in the same parse?

Comment: see updated answer